# How do I create a .htaccess file that would make my website work like Adfly

Tags: php, htaccess

I need, but don't know how to make, an *htaccess* file that will send a user, when looking for the home page, to *index.php*.  It should not send them anywhere when they look for a URL like `/7fg4/`.

Adfly, to the best of my knowledge, works like this: you make a link, it stores the shortened link. When the user tries to open the link the *htaccess* file sends them the contents of another file which reads the URL and proceeds accordingly. 
My website should work almost exactly as Adfly does.

Can anyone explain or write an *htaccess* file that would do this?

Comment: I suggest you read into the basics of [URL rewriting](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/). Or do you have any specific problem?

Answer (score 2):

You want to implement permanent redirects in *.htaccess*. To redirect the home page to *default.php* you need:

```
redirect permanent index.html http://example.com/default.php
```

`index.html` is the default document on most servers.  To redirect the home page, you have to redirect the default document.   In that rule, you would need to replace `example.com` with your own domain name.

---

Instead of redirecting the home page to *default.php*, I would recommend making that file your home page.  To do so, you have to change the default document with a directive like this:

```
DirectoryIndex default.php
```

Then the contents of *default.php* will be served at the home page and users will never see `default.php` in the URL.